# Why is Esperanto posting about Flash?

Tags: bug, ios-app

[image: Bugged image]
<sup>(click to expand image)</sup>

The iOS app appears to be loading the wrong site icon for blog posts on the Feed.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.3.3 (Build 14G60)

Comment: Maybe it means something different in Esperanto.

Comment: People are still pushing Esperanto? More like *Espera**no***

Comment: People are still pushing Flash?